# Purpose of multiple assignment var x = this.x = function(){}?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, mootools, variable-assignment

In Mootools the following pattern occurs frequently:

```
var x = this.x = function(){}
```

For example:

```
var typeOf = this.typeOf = function(item){ ...
```

I understand multiple assignment results in `function` being assigned to both `x` and `this.x`. But I thought in the global scope `x` is implicitly `this.x`, so it seems redundant. Is this an optimization technique, or is there some other purpose to this pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only redundant if this code isn't executed in a function.

If it's in a function, the var is local, even if the context (`this`) is the global one.

Look at this :

```
function a() {
   var x = 1;
   console.log(x)
}
function b() {
   console.log(x); // fails
}
a();
b();
```

If you want to be both able to use `x` directly in `a` and have `this.x` in `b`, then you need the double assignation :

```
 var x = this.x = 1;
```

I frequently use this pattern in big functions when I have a variable I use a lot and for which I prefer a direct access without `this.`.

Comment: I overlooked that it was wrapped in a function. Makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

var x is not equals this.x, var x is a varible private of a js class and this.x is a public propertie, so the code create 2 ways for invoke a function
Here an example:

```
function exampleA() {
   this.x = 1;
   var x = 2;
   this.show = function () {
    alert("A.x:" + x);
    alert("A.this.x:" + this.x);
   };
}
function exampleB() {
   var x = this.x = 1;
   this.x   +=1; 
   this.show = function () {
    alert("B.x:" + x);
    alert("B.this.x:" + this.x);
   };
}
$(document).ready(

function () {
    var example1 = new exampleA();
    example1.show();
    var example1 = new exampleB();
    example1.show();
});
```